# Cron Job with Cakephp ACL permission

Tags: cakephp, cron, acl

I am building a website using Cakephp 2.0 ACL. I am wondering if it is possible to allow access to a controller/actions without auth and acl permissions so that my cron job can run these processes on regular intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered creating a CakePhp [Shell Script](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell) and then using a [Cron job to run it](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html)?

A shell task will allow you to access your applications models which is where you your business logic is, right?

Consider your shell task as a controller of sorts, which will instantiate and interact with your models. Your cron job then calls this task and collects any output.